# SQL Server Profiler and RDP session

Tags: remote-desktop, sql-server

does SQL Server Profiler continue to profile also if I close the program and log out from the RDP session?

Thank you all for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run profiler/trace as a SQL Server Agent job to run at specified times without having to log in. If you log off while manually running profiler, the application will close and stop the process.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you have a remote connection to a server on which you are running SQL Server Profiler.  If you simply close the connection without logging out from the remote server, Profiler will continue to run.